# Browser key code list?

Tags: javascript, keyboard, cross-browser

I know this is probably going to be in vain but I want to see if there is an answer. I'm making an HTML5 game and I'm trying to get keyboard input. Please tell me someone knows something google doesn't. Hopefully at least it'll stress how much keyboard events and keycodes need to be made more cross-browser.

Please tell me there is some kind of object in the javascript api that lists each key's keycode. And if not, why hasn't it been done yet, just being able to grab a key's code would make our jobs so much easier. No more testing the inconsistencies per browser/os.

And if not that (this is probably more in vain) is there a way to redefine the default keycodes to our own custom keycodes?

I don't know why more work hasn't been done to make this more convenient?

Comment: Handling javascript keyboard events is a nightmare :-( See http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html for full details.

Answer (score 12):

I find [this](http://www.w3.org/2002/09/tests/keys.html) page to be very helpful. Also [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html#t00) has a good article on it. Fact of the matter is that there's browser inconsistencies and a javascript framework like jQuery help with that.

Comment: I did consider using that but I don't want to add any unnecessary overhead to my game, for the most speed. So huge libraries like that aren't an option.

Comment: adding libraries doesn't really add overhead. Unless you are /doing/ something with the library. You just have to be smart about what you do (and mostly /when/ you do it)
Especially one like jquery that doesn't pollute the global namespace. (small download overhead, but js performance won't notice)
The overhead would be added when you use the library to do things, and don't understand /how/ it's doing these things, but largely the developer time savings greatly outweighs any 'performance overhead'

Comment: Link-only answers are not answers.

Answer (score 7):

JavaScript does not include a built-in hash of keycode-to-keyname pairings.

It's largely unnecessary because JS uses the same keycodes as are reported by the Operating System. Adding a hash would only hinder the performance unnecessarily.

The program doesn't need to know what the name of the key was, it just needs to know what action to take.

Instead of writing code like:

```
if (e.keyCode === customKeyList.UP)
{
  doUp();
}
```

You can simply set your own hash of actions:

```
//before the event
actions = {
  '38': function () {
    //do UP stuff here
  },
  '40': function () {
    //do DOWN stuff here
  }
};
//during the event
if (actions[e.keyCode]) {
  actions[e.keyCode]();
}
```

At no point in that example is it necessary for the *computer* to know the name of the key, but for convenience it may be useful to write it as:

```
actions[keys.UP] = function () {...};
actions[keys.DOWN] = function () {...};
```

but you'll need to define your own keycode-to-keyname pairing object.

---

I recently discovered that jQuery UI has a list of some commonly used keycodes (`$.ui.keyCode`):

```
keyCode: {
    ALT: 18,
    BACKSPACE: 8,
    CAPS_LOCK: 20,
    COMMA: 188,
    COMMAND: 91,
    COMMAND_LEFT: 91, // COMMAND
    COMMAND_RIGHT: 93,
    CONTROL: 17,
    DELETE: 46,
    DOWN: 40,
    END: 35,
    ENTER: 13,
    ESCAPE: 27,
    HOME: 36,
    INSERT: 45,
    LEFT: 37,
    MENU: 93, // COMMAND_RIGHT
    NUMPAD_ADD: 107,
    NUMPAD_DECIMAL: 110,
    NUMPAD_DIVIDE: 111,
    NUMPAD_ENTER: 108,
    NUMPAD_MULTIPLY: 106,
    NUMPAD_SUBTRACT: 109,
    PAGE_DOWN: 34,
    PAGE_UP: 33,
    PERIOD: 190,
    RIGHT: 39,
    SHIFT: 16,
    SPACE: 32,
    TAB: 9,
    UP: 38,
    WINDOWS: 91 // COMMAND
}
```

Comment: Put that jquery UI part on the top of your answer =), possibly with the link: http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.ui.keyCode/

Answer (score 2):

You can find the key bindings for most browsers by capturing a keypress and examining the event object- it may have a set of virtual key bindings.

Mozilla returns this set-

```
Property    Value
CANCEL=     3
HELP=   6
BACK_SPACE=     8
TAB=    9
CLEAR=  12
RETURN=     13
ENTER=  14
SHIFT=  16
CONTROL=    17
ALT=    18
PAUSE=  19
CAPS_LOCK=  20
KANA=   21
HANGUL=     21
JUNJA=  23
FINAL=  24
HANJA=  25
KANJI=  25
ESCAPE=     27
CONVERT=    28
NONCONVERT=     29
ACCEPT=     30
MODECHANGE=     31
SPACE=  32
PAGE_UP=    33
PAGE_DOWN=  34
END=    35
HOME=   36
LEFT=   37
UP=     38
RIGHT=  39
DOWN=   40
SELECT=     41
PRINT=  42
EXECUTE=    43
PRINTSCREEN=    44
INSERT=     45
DELETE=     46
0=  48
1=  49
2=  50
3=  51
4=  52
5=  53
6=  54
7=  55
8=  56
9=  57
SEMICOLON=  59
EQUALS=     61
A=  65
B=  66
C=  67
D=  68
E=  69
F=  70
G=  71
H=  72
I=  73
J=  74
K=  75
L=  76
M=  77
N=  78
O=  79
P=  80
Q=  81
R=  82
S=  83
T=  84
U=  85
V=  86
W=  87
X=  88
Y=  89
Z=  90
CONTEXT_MENU=   93
SLEEP=  95
NUMPAD0=    96
NUMPAD1=    97
NUMPAD2=    98
NUMPAD3=    99
NUMPAD4=    100
NUMPAD5=    101
NUMPAD6=    102
NUMPAD7=    103
NUMPAD8=    104
NUMPAD9=    105
MULTIPLY=   106
ADD=    107
SEPARATOR=  108
SUBTRACT=   109
DECIMAL=    110
DIVIDE=     111
F1=     112
F2=     113
F3=     114
F4=     115
F5=     116
F6=     117
F7=     118
F8=     119
F9=     120
F10=    121
F11=    122
F12=    123
F13=    124
F14=    125
F15=    126
F16=    127
F17=    128
F18=    129
F19=    130
F20=    131
F21=    132
F22=    133
F23=    134
F24=    135
NUM_LOCK=   144
SCROLL_LOCK=    145
COMMA=  188
PERIOD=     190
SLASH=  191
BACK_QUOTE=     192
OPEN_BRACKET=   219
BACK_SLASH=     220
CLOSE_BRACKET=  221
QUOTE=  222
META=   224
```

Answer (score 2):

The [keycodes.js](https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/8294cd7b14902717d2f1cab53d80025721d75a83/closure/goog/events/keycodes.js) and [keyhandler.js](https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/8294cd7b14902717d2f1cab53d80025721d75a83/closure/goog/events/keyhandler.js) classes from Google Closure library have a list of many key codes and useful comments about differencies across different browsers.

Comment: @TankorSmash The links has been changed. Fixed now.

Comment: Links are broken again...

Comment: Link-only answers are not answers.